# Bourbon 3.1.8 and Sass 3.3.2 (Maptastic Maple) not getting along

Tags: sass, bourbon

I have install latest sass and latest bourbon and I'm getting this error:

`>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
      error main.scss (Line 1: File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon/b
ourbon.
Load path: C:/xampp/htdocs/FJavaScriptjQueryInfinite_Skills_-_Learning_jQuery_Tr
aining_Video/sass (DEPRECATED))`

I have tried manually using bourbon from folder, but keep getting the same error.

Help -(.